# filter using AND OR - return only if all conditions are met

Tags: mysql

I need to filter the MySQL data based on user inputs (checkboxes) but the query I'm using it's not working as expected.

I'm using 3 columns (and 3 groups of checkboxes) to filter the data: type, status and bhk (all integers).

```
if ($filter_type != NULL) {
    foreach ($filter_type as $type=>$value) {
        if ($type === 0) {
            $type_cond = "AND t2.type = " . $value;
        } else {
            $type_cond .= " OR t2.type = " . $value;
        }
    }
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                               FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                               INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                               WHERE t2.use = ?
                               ' . $type_cond . '
                               ' . $status_cond . '
                               ' . $bhk_cond . '
                               ' . $filter_city . '
                               ' . $filter_zone . '
                               LIMIT ?, ?'))
```

The same for the other two. In the table `property` I have 1 row: type = 2, status = 0 and bhk = 3.

I check the checkboxes type 1 and 2, bhk 1 (`AND type = 1 OR type = 2 AND bhk = 1`): returns nothing, ok. If I continue checking bhk 3: it returns the row, ok. But If I also want to filter by the status:

```
AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2
AND t2.bhk = 1 or t2.bhk = 3
AND t2.status = 1 OR t2.status = 2
```

Why the above sentence returns the row? The last AND and OR are not true. What I need is that: only return the data that matches the 3 ANDs/ORs (or the 2 in case one of the 3 groups are not used).

How can I do that?

Also I have some doubts: (first example)

```
AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2
AND t2.status = 0 --OR t2.status = 1 
AND t2.bhk = 1
```

Not returning the row... But if I add `OR t2.status = 1` it will return the row... why?

(second example)

```
AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2
AND t2.status = 1
AND t2.bhk = 3 --OR t2.bhk = 1
```

It doesn't make any sense... Please enlighten me.

The second question is: Why does `AND does t2.status = 0` not return the row but `AND t2.status = 0 OR t2.status = 1` does? (based on the first example)

EDIT: Add new script (use `IN()` instead of `OR`)

```
$type_count = count($filter_type);
$type_cond = '';
if ($filter_type != NULL) {
    foreach ($filter_type as $type=>$value) {
        if ($type === 0) {
            $type_cond = 'AND t2.type IN ( ' . $value;
            if ($type_count === 1) {
                $condition .= ')';
            }
        } else if ($type < $count) {
            $type_cond .= ', ' . $value;
        } else {
            $type_cond .= ', ' . $value . ')';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might want to add some parenthesis around those ORs

Comment: Even if there's only 1 OR? Sorry I've never used parenthesis. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter:

```
AND t2.type = 1 OR t2.type = 2
AND t2.bhk = 1 or t2.bhk = 3
AND t2.status = 1 OR t2.status = 2
```

Could aswell be written asL

```
AND t2.type = 1 OR (t2.type = 2
AND t2.bhk = 1) or (t2.bhk = 3
AND t2.status = 1) OR t2.status = 2
```

That is it returns TRUE if `t2.status = 2` regardless of the rest of it. You can fix it using proper parantheses but it probably be better if you use `IN`

```
AND t2.type IN (1,2)
AND t2.bhk IN (1,3)
AND t2.status IN (1,2)
```

Comment: `IN` seems to do what I need, I'm going to test it a little, thanks! +1